# Cannot compile when I include the Windows.Devices.Enumeration.h file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a Visual Studio 2017 C++17 MFC project on Windows 10 using Windows SDK 10.0.18362.0.
I need to add code to enumerate and connect to a Bluetooth LE device.

To start off, the first thing I need to do is to

```
#include <winrt/Windows.Devices.Enumeration.h>
```

The winrt/ header files are in
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt\winrt

If I wanted to go with the ABI:: headers then I would

```
#include <Windows.Devices.Enumeration.h>
```

Those header files are in
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\winrt

Here is the problem. If I comment out this include, I have no compile errors but if I add either one I get compile errors.

Regardless of which include I use I get a mountain of errors such as
Error   C2059   syntax error: 'constant'
which points to DirectXMathVector.inl (a MS C++ Math Library) the line pointed to is

```
XMVECTOR A = XMVectorSelect(g_XMSelect1110.v, V, g_XMSelect1110.v);
```

Or, if I use the 2nd ABI include mentioned above I get a ton of compile errors such as
Error   C2027   use of undefined type 'ABI::Windows::Foundation::Internal::GetAbiType'
which is in the windows.foundation.collections.h file and the line pointed to is

```
typedef typename Windows::Foundation::Internal::GetAbiType<T>::type _abi_type;
```

So what's the deal?  How can VS2017 with C++2017 and a recent SDK not be able to compile MS's own files?  Does this compile with VS2019? I don't have that to test.

TIA,

Ed

Comment: Compiles for me with the oldest online version I can find (probably not old enough) - live - https://godbolt.org/z/hxh1KjjTP

Comment: This is the first time that I have seen an on-line compiler.  I see the designation msvc v19.14.  I guess I am missing something but I don't understand what the v19.14 is referring to.  My VS 2017 Platform Toolset is v141, the redist that I have is 14.31.nnn, My VS Pro 2017 version is 15.9.48.  I do see that MS has a Version 19.14 for Make.PowerApps.com and App.PowerApps.com.  Is that what the v19.14 refers to?  Is that VS 2017?  I just wouldn't be able to compare an on-line compiler with an actual copy of VS 2017.

Comment: From the Developer Command Prompt enter `cl /?` and you will get a page of output at the top it should say something like `Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.32.31329 for x86`  ie it's the compiler version, this is from MSVS 2022.

Comment: As soon as I wrote the previous comment the idea of it being _MSC_VER hit me.  the cl command doesn't work in VS 2017 but regardless my _MSC_VER is 1916.  So maybe it is the Windows SDK where these header files are located.  I don't see an SDK selector in the on-line compiler.  Thanks again.  I'll keep plugging away.

Comment: As a follow up.  The thing that I found that worked was a Project Properties setting. Properties > C/C++ > General node in the left pane. Set the Consume Windows Runtime Extension property to Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a follow up. The thing that I found that worked was a Project Properties setting. Properties > C/C++ > General node in the left pane. Set the Consume Windows Runtime Extension property to Yes

Comment: Hi , Please consider  clicking   '✔' to mark it as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: I don't see anywhere on the page that has a place to check a box for accepted answer.  Where should it be?

Comment: See the [✔](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaFvo.png) .